# Sharepoint Online Error:The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-online

Currently I am trying to connect to SharePoint via Console Application authentication.
The error returned is:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SharePointOnlineCredentials to pass the credential.

The following example code for your reference.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string targetSiteURL = @"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";

    var login = "lz@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    var password = "xxx";   

    var securePassword = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }
    SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
    ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(web);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    Console.ReadKey();             
}
```

Comment: web not found, no declare of web

Comment: I modify the reply, you can check it.

Comment: The error: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.